# Sync Outlook notes API for Android

Tags: android, outlook, cloud

I have an Android application, which allows users to create notes, with different notification settings. But there is an idea to sync the application with other note and calendar appointment providers (Google Calendar e.t.c.). After a few hours of internet surfing, I couldn't find any documentation on Outlook Notes.

So the question is: Is there a public API (or any possibility) to sync in a custom application Outlook Notes/Calendar Appointments?

Any help would be great. Thanks is advice.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am looking for something like this too.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no... After a few days of search I gave up... but... I remember I saw a few apps that can sync with Exchange servers... mostly mail. Google Calendar seams to work with it... but honestly I don't know how.